# This is probably not the site you were looking for error

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, google-chrome

One of our clients receives this error when attempting to access our app. The error message is:

"You attempted to reach `xxx.foo.com`, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as `yyy.bar.com`. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious ... "

The only request in our application that goes to `yyy.bar.com` is a javascript file in our header (format: `https://yyy.bar.com/script.js`).

I have been unable to duplicate this issue locally, and no other users are reporting this issue. I'm convinced it is a setting on the client's machine, but after trolling around in Chrome's content settings/certificate management pages, I am unable to figure out what might be causing this to only happen to one specific client.

(Note, **all** of the client's machines are affected. Maybe its some antivirus configuration, or a problem with their router?)

Comment: Hi Mike. The reason the error is occurring is simple - the browser is making an SSL connection to `xxx.foo.com` and is getting a certificate for `yyy.bar.com`. Are both sites the same - as in, serving the same content, with one configured as an alias of the other in the webserver config?

Answer (score 1):

They're running Chrome on Windows XP, which doesn't support SSL SNI when running on XP because it uses the MS crypto library.  **(Update: Chrome versions 6.0 and newer on Windows XP do support SNI)**  It'll reproduce in that situation (or with IE on XP, as well). For a more complete list of browser support for SNI, see [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Browsers_with_support_for_TLS_server_name_indication.5B5.5D) section.

For working clients, they're accessing a resource within `https://xxx.foo.com` and, because they support SNI, they're getting the `xxx.foo.com` cert presented by the web server.

For this Windows XP client, it's requesting a resource from `https://xxx.foo.com` and getting the default certificate for that SSL port; the `yyy.foo.com` cert, which is invalid for that name.

What's your web server, and how are its SSL listeners configured?

Comment: FYI, Chrome on XP does support SNI (from version 6 and up). We're now at version 24 and with Chromiums auto-update functionality you won't encounter any clients running Chrome 5 or lower. Did you mean IE? IE8 on WinXP does not support SNI. Tested up to Safari 5.1 (XP) and it did not work either. The [Wikipedia article on browser support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Browsers_with_support_for_TLS_server_name_indication.5B5.5D) is pretty accurate

Comment: @Lekensteyn You're absolutely right, just this answer showing its age.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

Use PORT or IP based virtual hosting.  HOSTNAME based virtual hosting is not compatible with using SSL on both hosts.

Comment: Yep. SNI is not ready for prime time yet.